# How to filter multiple table entries with search

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-table

How do I filter through the tables and only show the ones matching the keywords the user types? 
I want to be able to have multiple tables within the page, but I want to still be able to show and hide based on user input.

```
                <!--    <table class="responsive-stacked-table with-mobile-labels tablesection">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Submitted By</th>
                            <th>Egg or Nestling?</th>
                            <th>How Many?</th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                            <th>Description of Nest</th>
                            <th>Possible Species?</th>
                            <th>Edit // Delete</th>

                        </tr> -->
                        <br><table class="responsive-stacked-table with-mobile-labels tablesection">
                       <tr>
                            <th>Submitted By</th>
                            <th>Date Submitted</th>
                            <th>Egg or Nestling?</th>
                            <th>How Many?</th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                            <th>Description of Nest</th>
                            <th>Possible Species?</th>
                            <th>Edit // Delete</th>

                        </tr><tr><td data-label='Submitted By:' ><img src='images/profilepics/levi.jpg'class= 'img-circle submittedbypicture' > <br>partymo</td><td data-label='Date Submitted:' ><br> Last Edited: <br> </td><td data-label='Egg or Nestling:' >egg</td><td  data-label='How Many:'>3</td><td  data-label='Location:'>$nest['profilepicfile']</td><td  data-label='Description:'>$nest['profilepicfile']</td><td  data-label='Possible Species:'>edit if you know!</td><td><a href="edit.php?id=4">Edit</a> // <a href="delete.php?id=4">Delete</a></td></tr></table><br><br><br><br><table class="responsive-stacked-table with-mobile-labels tablesection">
                       <tr>
                            <th>Submitted By</th>
                            <th>Date Submitted</th>
                            <th>Egg or Nestling?</th>
                            <th>How Many?</th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                            <th>Description of Nest</th>
                            <th>Possible Species?</th>
                            <th>Edit // Delete</th>

                        </tr><tr><td data-label='Submitted By:' ><img src='images/profilepics/rubert.jpg'class= 'img-circle submittedbypicture' > <br>robster</td><td data-label='Date Submitted:' >2017-08-09<br> Last Edited: <br> 2017-08-11</td><td data-label='Egg or Nestling:' >nestling</td><td  data-label='How Many:'>4</td><td  data-label='Location:'>4</td><td  data-label='Description:'>really big. </td><td  data-label='Possible Species:'>edit if you know!</td><td><a href="edit.php?id=9">Edit</a> // <a href="delete.php?id=9">Delete</a></td></tr></table><br><br><br>
```

Comment: why not using table plugins?

Comment: [AngularJS has a great filter.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) See the example section at the bottom of the page. If you don't want to use a framework, it can be done in vanilla JS. What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you basically want tables that can be filtered using a textbox?

If you're thinking js-based client-side filtering, and you're fine using jQuery, you could set up your HTML like so:

```
<input type="textbox" class="fitler-input" data-for="filterable-table1">
<table id="filterable-table1">
  ...
</table>
```

then you could use jQuery to do something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function filterfunction(tablerow,testvalue) {
    // sample filter: include rows where any cell contains the testvalue text
    return tablerow.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(testvalue.toLowerCase()) > -1;
}

jQuery(function($){

    $(".filter-input").each(function(){ // start by iterating all filter textboxes
        var $filter = $(this); // select the filter
        var $table = $("#"+$filter.data("for")); // select this filter's table

        $filter.on("change keydown keyup keypress", function(){ // whenever user types in box,
            setTimeout(function(){ // timeout makes the value retrieval more instant
                var $rows = $table.find(">tr, >tbody>tr"); // get all table rows
                var value = $filter.val(); // get this filter's new value
                $rows.each(function(){ // go through all rows, and test against filter
                    var $row = $(this); // get this row
                    if(filterfunction($row,value)) // test this row
                        $row.show(); // it matches
                    else
                        $row.hide(); // it doesn't match
                });
            },1);
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

This would also be something you could do in vanilla js (i.e., using no libraries), but it'd take a bit more time and code.

And [here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/codesmith32/g92kwykL/) to demonstrate it in action.

**EDIT:**
Just my opinion, but:

As per @Peter-Rakmanyi's comment, if your site / webapp / interface is heavily data-driven, and you plan on having a lot of HTML manipulation based on user input, AngularJS might be something you should consider looking into. It would require a little refactoring of your HTML (which might mean some php tweaks), but it may be worth it.

If this is one of only a few small cases you'll need filtering for, you can probably just get away with using jQuery.

Comment: thank you for such an amazing answer..I think I misspoke. I meant like 1 search bar for all tables. The search bar filters the tables based on user input.

Comment: Sure! You could easily change the "for" data attribute to a class, and then just add the class to all tables that one input should affect. E.g., note the '.' versus the '#': `var $table = $("."+$filter.data("for")); // select this filter's table`